# How to set color at the background of the value

Tags: html, css, servicenow

I have a code which sets values in the table columns, now for text which displays has a black color but i want to highlight the text with the background of blue color

Below is my current HTML code

```html
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table  table-responsive-sm table-bordered border-dark">
        <caption style="caption-side: top;">
          
          <h2 style="color:red">Country wise live updates</h2>
        </caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Country</th>
            <th scope="col">Total Affected</th>
            <th scope="col">Deaths</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{{data.country}}</td>
            <td>{{data.total}}</td>
            <td>{{data.deaths}}</td>

          </tr>
        
                
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

   
  </body>
```

current output:

[image]

Expected out to be highlighted only text part.

I want to display the output as shown below:

[image]

Comment: So you need your <td> outputs to have a blue background if i understand correct?

Comment: Did you search this query on Google ? If no please try and if yes Try [mark element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark) with css. Thanks

Comment: If you are not doing this for your government just let it be. The last thing people need is a possible source to false information about COVID-19

Comment: Unless this is a site made for the government we should not support this as it might be a possible source of false information about COVID-19

Comment: @Dejan.S
This is nothing related to government, I am in a intial stage developer so just learning for my side. This i am doing in my personal instnace

Comment: @AbdulAzeez fair enough, a lot of sites popping up with covid-19 that lead to missinformation, it's a serious issue so just making sure. Good luck with the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the value in a span with a class.

```css
.table-cell-blue {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table  table-responsive-sm table-bordered border-dark">
      <caption style="caption-side: top;">

        <h2 style="color:red">Country wise live updates</h2>
      </caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col"><span class="table-cell-blue">Country</span></th>
          <th scope="col">Total Affected</th>
          <th scope="col">Deaths</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>{{data.country}}</td>
          <td>{{data.total}}</td>
          <td>{{data.deaths}}</td>

        </tr>


      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the whole column you can use the :first-child or :nth-child(number) to select however many you want for that column, and i have gave each td column their own class so you can choose which ones you want selected for each column

```
<style>
      .td-Country:nth-child(2){
        background-color: dodgerblue;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table  table-responsive-sm table-bordered border-dark">
        <caption style="caption-side: top;">
          <h2 style="color:red">Country wise live updates</h2>
        </caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Country</th>
            <th scope="col">Total Affected</th>
            <th scope="col">Deaths</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="td-Countryt">{{data.country}}</td>
            <td class="td-Total">{{data.total}}</td>
            <td class="td-Deaths">{{data.deaths}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: @ShrewStyle

This is appliying for the entire column, how to make it highlited for only a text but not all the entire column

Comment: @AbdulAzeez so you only want just data.country or just data.total?
Or do you mean you only want a single element in data.country or a single element in data.total?

Comment: I will get the value as 10 or 20 or 3000 in data.total same goes to other fields as well. When i used your scirpt all the entire column is changing. We have something called mark element which is works perfectly fine but it is highlighted even i dont an output in the column

Comment: @AbdulAzeez i have amended the html and css above, if you only need a select few in the column use the :nth-child and :first-child parameters etc... this will choose only the ones you want, i have also changed the classes for each of the country, total and deaths so they don't all get selected together, if this is still not what you are after post a codepen showing the issues, of course you will need to add more fields into the colums for these selectors to work

Comment: I am sorry if i am making you trouble to explain, update the question with the output, It fills the entire the td column which do not want i want to hightlight only the text part but not the entire part. Please review 2 attachments. 1 is to for expected out and another is what i am getting now

Comment: Ahhh ok i think i understand what you mean now, if you would like the background-color only to wrap around the text and not the entire column element you would have to create a separate div inside of the column and then set that div with a background color, i've made an example but there is not a out of the box way to do this with css https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-water-kffyd

Answer (score 0):

You would just create a style for a class then change the background colour of that class:

```
<style>
    .highlighted {
         background-color: blue;
         display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
```

You would then apply that class to any element you want to be highlighted blue.

Comment: Hi Tyler,
When i apply the code the code to a class it is applying to the entire table and column, i want to highlight only the value or text part but not the entire column / table.

Comment: @AbdulAzeez I have fixed that for you now, all that was need is the `display: inline-block;` this basically makes it so the div only takes up the height and width that the content takes up.